# Is it possible to access github.com through git-credential-manager-core.exe? How to implement it？

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I'm developing git third-party tools. I want to call git-credential-manager-core.exe in C / C + + through external program instead of GIT command line.Can anybody point to an example or guidance on how to best hook this up?

Comment: The Git credential managers generally don't *access* any external sites (though each one can do whatever it wants of course): their purpose is to store *credentials* (authentication data) that *other programs* can use to make such accesses, but not to do the accessing themselves. So you're looking in the wrong place. Note: Git doesn't do this accessing either: it runs a credential manager to get credentials, then passes the credentials to the libcurl library to make https requests. The actual connection is thus done in libcurl.

Comment: I've added the Microsoft.Alm.Authentication to help with Authentication and credential manager access. It works great for retrieving credentials that are already entered from the command line.
However is there any way to also hook into the Credential Manager's Login UI that prompts for username and password for Github. This UI pops up automatically from the command line, but doesn't fire when using cmd or External program.

Comment: I have no idea—I don't do Windows, just Linux/Unix systems.

Comment: @torek,Thank you for your professional reply, let me have a certain understanding of Microsoft. ALM. Authentication